# Soft Question - Motivation of the Pettis Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, soft-question

What is the use/motivation of the Pettis Integral? When is it used when the Bochner integral cannot be used?

Comment: The two agree for separable Banach spaces, so the difference only matters for nonseparable Banach spaces, where more functions are generally Pettis integrable.